# Is there a way to differentiate several wheel of same package in a pip server?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a pip server that I would like to use to easily deploy some Python package of my own (wrappers of C++ code). The name of my wheel is handled by my `setup` function from `setuptools`.

I am in a case where, depending on my C++ build, I can have several wheels with the same name, but with a different library inside (like debug / release, with GPU programming / without GPU programming ...).

I can use a custom server to handle the wheels for me but I would like to know if I can use some specifier to differentiate several wheels containing the same named package in a pip server?

Answer (score 1):

Nop. `pip` [can distinguish](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/) distributions by Python platform (CPython/PyPy/Jython), Python version, OS platform (Linux, w32, MacOS), 32- vs 64-bit processor, [UCS2 vs UCS4](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) python. But that's all. Everything else must be in the package's name.

Comment: That's what I thought but then, how does libraries like TensorFlow handle all their possibilities on a platform? If I have a GPU or not, if I have AVX support... The pip installation of TensorFlow won't build it while if you build tensorflow from its sources, you need to specify whether you want GPU support or not. How do they identify the best build for my system since GPU support isn't set in the wheel name for example?

Comment: [tensorflow-gpu](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/) vs [tensorflow](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/). And there are no sources, only binary wheels. To compile from sources you have to start at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow. [Nightly build with GPU](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly-gpu/) and [without](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/). Different packages, no way around that.